# Question about moment of inertia calculation and logic

Tags: mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

Question:

Determine the moment of inertia for a quadrant of a uniform circular lamina of radius b.

Here I saw the answer that,however I don't understand it first of all here is the answer and I will post what I don't understand about it.

$I_z = \int R^2 \rho ds = \int_0^b \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} sin^2(\theta) r^3 \rho d\theta dr$

Alright first of all why did we take the moment of inertia about the z-axis why not y or x. Secondly I don't understand the bounds or specifically for calculation of $d\theta$ can someone clarify ??

Comment: It doesn't sound like this object is symmetric about the $z$ axis at all, why do you think they used symmetry in their calculations? Please post the *full* question and solution you're confused about, including the equations defining the object you're studying.

Comment: alright 1 moment I will post everything including the question

Comment: I have edited the question if you can check it that would be great.

Comment: That can't be the entirety of the question: you must have left out the part where it specifies the axis and reference point with which you are to compute the moment of inertia. (The answer only makes sense if the axis is coplanar to the quarter-circle and bisects it through the origin).

Comment: I see well if we assume that then yes the geometry would make sense but can you explain why did we take the angle to be from $-\pi/4$ to $\pi/4$  if we take the axis of rotating to be about the symmetry axis ?

Comment: Draw a picture. The apex angle of the quarter-circle is $\pi/2$ (one-quarter of $2\pi$) and half of that is $\pi/4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If body is rotating around specific axes, quantity you are looking for is called angular momentum of inertia.

$L = r \times mv = I\omega e_z = I_z\omega$, where $r$ - is a vector from rotation axe to the point, $v$ is a vector of speed, $m$ is a inertial ass of the point, $\omega$ - angular velocity and $\omega r = v$,$m = \rho s$ where $\rho$ - is an area density and $s$ is area of "point" of mass. Because rotation is happening in x-y plane, vector product is going to be along z-axe.

Switching to polar coordinates for the circle wedge we are having: $$I_z = \int r^2 dm = \int r^2 \rho ds = \int_0^b \int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}r^3\rho drd\theta$$
So there is no way $\sin(\theta)$ comes from ... unless some additional conditions are missing.

**UPDATE**

The only way you can get $\sin^2(\theta)$ under integral if disk has it thinkness or density proportional to $\sin^2(\theta)$ ... so it will be not a disk but some strange object.